# MATLAB- Joining tables w/ overlapping data using key variable WHERE neither table contains all data points from the other one

Tags: matlab, dataset

I am working on combining 2 tables with different types of patient information using the PID (Patient Identity) feature present in both tables. Usually the function "join" (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.join.html) does the trick when one of the tables have information on all the patients from the other one. But in my case, both tables have certain values of PID (or information for new patients) that isn't present in the other one. How do I create a new table for using patient info from both tables that only contains info on the patients present in both tables?

I could probably write some long, clunky code to do this manually, but I was wondering if there's a function (or a few functions) that can do the task more efficiently. Thank you

Comment: Use either [innerjoin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/innerjoin.html) or [outerjoin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use either innerjoin or outerjoin.